# Use ng-repeat ( AngularJS) with EJS and express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express, ejs

Is it possible to perform Angular operations such as ng-repeat within the EJS templating engine for the purpose of **TWO WAY DATA BINDING**?

**If so, can you provide an example of how to pass an array from express to EJS and perform ng-repeat.**

**My User Schema:**

```
 var mileSchema = mongoose.Schema({ miles: String });
 var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

local            : {
    email        : String,
    password     : String,
},
userInfo         : {
    fullname     : String,
    region       : String,
},
milesLog         : [mileSchema]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**My Express Route:**

```
var User       = require('../app/models/user');

app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user
    });
 });
```

**My EJS template:** ( this is only a section of the whole template )

```
<p ng-repeat="m in milesLog">{{m}}</p>

<% if (user.local.email) { %>
<p>
   <strong>id</strong>: <%= user._id %><br>
   <strong>email</strong>: <%= user.local.email%><br>
   <strong>Region</strong>: <%= user.userInfo.region %><br>
   <strong>username</strong>: <%= user.userInfo.fullname %><br> 
</p>
<% } %>
```